# elasticsearch filter with or condition

Tags: elasticsearch

```
GET cd.io.schema.securityissueinstance/_count
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {"must": [
        {
          "bool": {
              "should": [
                  {"term": {"risk_accepted": false}},
                  {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "risk_accepted"
                  }
                }
              ]
          }
        }
    ]}
  }
}
```

Here is my elasticsearch query where i am check if `risk_accepted` false or not exist or null
But, here i can't find any way i got way for exists only
I need to put those 3 or condition.

Please check how to do this

Answer (score 0):

[Exists Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html):

- The field in the source JSON is null or []
- The field has "index" : false set in the mapping
- The length of the field value exceeded an ignore_above setting in the mapping
- The field value was malformed and ignore_malformed was defined in the mapping

Query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "risk_accepted": false
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "exists": {
                  "field": "risk_accepted"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Will it work if risk_accepted null also ?

Comment: yes, The field in the source JSON is null or [].

Answer (score 0):

### risk_accepted is false OR not exists OR null

You have to the combination of the `term` and `bool`

```bash
GET cd.io.schema.securityissueinstance/_count
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "risk_accepted": false
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": [
                    {
                      "exists": {
                        "field": "risk_accepted"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": [
                    {
                      "exists": {
                        "field": "risk_accepted"
                      }
                    }
                  ],
                  "filter": {
                    "bool": {
                      "must_not": [
                        {
                          "bool": {
                            "should": [
                              {
                                "term": {
                                  "risk_accepted": false
                                }
                              },
                              {
                                "term": {
                                  "risk_accepted": true
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

- Outermost `bool` query has a `must` clause, which specifies that all conditions must be satisfied.
- Within `must` clause, another `bool` query with a `should` clause, => at least one of the conditions should satisfy.
- The first condition is a `term` query that matches documents where the value of `risk_accepted` is `false`.
- The second condition is a `bool` query with a `must_not` clause and an
  `exists` query that matches documents where the `risk_accepted` field
  does not exist.
- The third condition is a similar `bool` query with a
  `must_not` clause and an exists query, but with an additional filter
  clause that matches documents where the value of `risk_accepted` is
  neither `false` nor true.